# Insert Dynamic options into established <select> element of a kendo ui template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have a kendo template named *editor_template* and have a `<select>` element inside the template. The `<select>` is a drop down and could have any number of items of any kinds of names based on what info we pull from the user. So I am trying to find a way to insert `<option>` elements into the select, but so far had no luck.

I have tried things like:

```
$($('#editor_template').html()).find('#dropdownId').html().replace('variable', optionList);
```

which would grab my `<select>` element, and replace the variable, but no change was reflected in *editor_template*.

I also tried going after the `.innerHTML` instead of `html()` too with no luck.

Simply doing:

`$('#editor_template').html().replace('variable', optionList);`

didn't do anything.

I have `<select>variable</select>`, so replace on the variable should do it, but it doesn't replace anything.

How might get this `<select>` that is already stated in the kendo template specifically, then insert any number of options that I dynamically acquire into the dropdown?

Comment: I suggest you to complete understand everything wrote [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) before moving forward with your customization.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that documentation yet. The info on setting variables and then assigning values to the variables in templates will hopefully be very useful for this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that .replace() is a jQuery function and I'm unclear what 'variable' selector is...

Assuming dropdownID is the ID for your `<select>` tag and optionList contains HTML, try `$('#editor_template').find('#dropdownId').html(optionList);`

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. Replace is for strings in JS, which was why I was calling the html() function to get it in string form, then do a replace on the string

Comment: Should work, see tested on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/l0ul0u/sk71y7es/

Comment: I changed my variables where my options would go to the #=variable# syntax kendo says to use to insert html into the variables in their templates. then used:

var template = kendo.template($('#editor_template').html());
$('#editor_template').html(template({whatIdOptions: whatOptString, whoIdOptions: whoOptString}));

And that got my option lists into my template in place of variables. Thank you for the help!